# ROR: What is causing uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I had to update from Sendgrid V2 to V3. I am using the Sendgrid-ruby gem 5.3.

I am getting this error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant PasswordController::Email):
app/controllers/password_controller.rb:54:in `send_email' 
May 06 08:57:01 burro-staging app/web.1: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

Here is the line causing the issue (2nd line below).

```
  mail = SendGrid::Mail.new
  mail.from = Email.new(email: 'no-reply@getburro.com') <-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is looking for `Email` class and couldn't find it. The reason is because `Email` belongs to `Sendgrid` module, and should be scoped like so:

`Sendgrid::Email.new` ...

as can be seen here:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/9dd0cf6c9eb7ecc1e4fe2824f9638468ab5fc818/lib/sendgrid/helpers/mail/email.rb

```
module SendGrid
  class Email

    attr_accessor :email, :name

    def initialize(email: nil, name: nil)

...
```

And from the docs: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby#with-mail-helper-class